# Resolve and Send button are ghosted

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

[image]This is the last version of GUI (helium Hydra)
When filing amount + address resolve and send stay ghosted

**When doing it from wallet-cli i got the following output :**

Balance: 2.780233421625, unlocked balance: 2.780233421625
Background refresh thread started
wallet 43962j: transfer 4GdoN7NCTi8a5gZug7PrwZNKjvHFmKeV11L6pNJPgj5QNEHsN6eeX3DaAQFwZ1ufD4LYCZKArktt113W7QjWvQ7CWBJt6AK654322bFgz6 2.7
Wallet password: *************************

There is currently a 1 block backlog at that fee level. Is this okay?  (Y/Yes/N/No)y
Sending 2.700000000000.  The transaction fee is 0.015075840000
Is this okay?  (Y/Yes/N/No): y

Unsigned transaction(s) successfully written to file: unsigned_monero_tx
Balance: 2.780233421625, unlocked balance: 2.780233421625

And nothing happens (after several hours)

How to fix this ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using a view only wallet? Because your log kind of indicates that.

Comment: that's what i was fearing, don't know how i manage to do a read only wallet, is there a command to know what kind of wallet is it ?

Comment: ok seed command, it's a read only :)